# How do I prove that $D_n$ is isomorphic to the group generated by the two permutations given below?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$D_n = \langle a, b : a^n = b^2 = 1, ab = b^{-1} a \rangle$ and $H = \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle$, where $\alpha = (1 2 \cdots n)$ and $\beta = \pmatrix{1&2&3&\cdots &n-1&n \\ 1&n&n-1&\cdots&3&2}$.

We have to prove $|\alpha|=n$ and $|\beta|=2$ and that $G \cong H$.

It is clear to me that the order of $\alpha$ is $n$ being the length of the cycle, I don't know how to prove the order of $\beta$ is $2$ and that $H$ and $G$ are isomorphic. This isn't my homework, I'm working on general problems to prepare for my exams.

Comment: An permutation $\sigma$ has order $n$ if $\sigma^n = \operatorname{id}$ (but $\sigma^k \neq \operatorname{id}$ for any proper factor $k$ of $n$).

Comment: @Travis: Yes, it's obvious that $|\beta| = 2$. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the second relator doesn't look right, it should be: $ab = b a^{-1}$. (One can also remember this as $(ab)^2 = \operatorname{id}$---geometrically, this is a consequence of the fact that a reflection across a line followed by a rotation is the same operation as a reflection across some other line.) Since $b^2 = \operatorname{id}$, we have $b^{-1} = b$, and so as written the relator simply says that $a$ and $b$ commute, and so the presentation gives the group $\Bbb Z_n \times \Bbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Show, using the given relators of $D_n$, that any element of $D_n$ can be written as $a^k b^l$ for some $0 \leq k < n$ and $0 \leq l < 2$. Use this to write down an explicit candidate isomorphism $G \cong H$.

Comment: I'm not seeing how I'd have to prove that every element of $D_n$ is some $a^k b^l$. I will think some more about this. Assuming I've proven it. Would the isomorphism then be $f : D_n \to H$ defined as $f(a^k b^l) = \alpha^k \beta ^l$?

Comment: Any element $g \in D_n$ can be written as a product of generators, i.e., as $a^{k_1} b^{l_1} \cdots a^{k_m} b^{k_m}$. If $m = 1$, that is, if we're given $g$ in the form $g = a^{k_1} b^{l_1}$, then we are done. If $m = 2$, that is, if we're given $g = a^{k_1} b^{l_1} a^{k_2} b^{l_2}$, how we can rewrite this as $a^{k'} b^{l'}$ for suitable $k', l'$ using the relator to write $ba$ in this form?

Comment: And that's certainly a sensible candidate: One can see immediately that it behaves in the right way for $l = 0$ and $k = 0$, as $a, \alpha$ have the right same order and so do $b, \beta$.